# How do you test your app with React-data-Grid ?

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I am trying to test my apps which used React-Data-Grid with the npm package react-test-renderer but it fails.

for example, I have copied the the basic example in a file Example.js 
https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/scripts/example01-basic.js

and I am calling the object.

```
describe('Testing ReactDataGrid ', () => {
  test('Render without crashing', () => {
    const myRender = renderer.create(<Example />)
    let tree = myRender.toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

but I have a crash ... here is the stack. Is there anybody who can help me ? Maybe somebody uses another library to test React-data-grid. 
Thank you.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of null

```
  at Canvas._this.getScroll (node_modules/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.js:9537:36)
  at Viewport._this.getScroll (node_modules/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.js:12791:28)
  at Grid.componentDidMount (node_modules/react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.js:10345:55)
  at commitLifeCycles (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6955:22)
  at commitAllLifeCycles (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8164:7)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2264:14)
  at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:219:27)
  at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:126:
```

Comment: Enzyme. I have same error, so I'm using Enzyme to render the component and doing less good tests.